# Termux error 502 and error: unable to locate package

Tags: termux

today i opened termux for installing node.js on my phone (because i need npm), but it doesn't work, i runned `pkg install nodejs` but it gave me the error: `unable to locate package nodejs`.
I checked my connection and i'm connected to wi-fi with a really good speed, so i tried to install another common package to see if the problem was only for the node.js package or in the whole app,
i tried to install git and it gave me the same error.
So i started searching in forums: stackoverflow, github forum, termux wiki, etc...
I tried everything, `apt update, pkg update, apt upgrade, pkg upgrade, etc...`
Those gave me the error: [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RE4P.png)
So, i don't know what to try anymore, please give me an answer, have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

This error is common one. You should change repository mirror for your termux packages.

Here is the instruction from the official Termux [github page](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/wiki/Package-Management).

To select multiple repositories press space. To select new mirror for repositories use space and then enter.

Answer (score 1):

Termux can be used for hacking and many other suspicious things which is definitely against playstore policies. So you just need to uninstall termux playstore version and download termux from F-Droid. That is actual termux not the play store one. You should not face any error in that termux.

Nothing else worked, neither running some command nor changing repo. The only thing which works is downloading termux from F droid

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).